# VB.NET | MySQL: A fatal error encountered during command executation

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm despairing because an mysql error is in my code and I didn't find any helpful answer.

**Code:**

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Server=" & host.Text & ";User Id=" & user.Text & ";Password=" & password.Text & ";Database=" & database.Text & ";"
    cmd.Connection = cn
    Try
        cn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" & directory.Text & "' INTO TABLE " & database.Text & "." & table.Text & ";"
        MsgBox(cmd.CommandText)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Catch exError As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error: " & exError.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    cn.Close()
```

Screenshot of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df2wn.png

Edit: Screenshot 2 of the error (more detailed): https://i.stack.imgur.com/UREaq.png

When I use this line:

```
cmd.CommandText = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/Bibliothek/Desktop/test.txt' INTO TABLE test.test;
```

it works.

Comment: What are the real names of the database and the table?

Comment: I use my local database. So it's test and test.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MySql but `LOAD DATA` does not look  like something you would execute with `ExecuteReader`. `ExecuteNonQuery` is probably  more appropriate. Also, if you use `exError.ToString()` instead of just `Message`, you will get a lot more information.

Comment: Actually, thats the error msg **you** coded.  The original NET exception will usually have more information, details and/or an inner exception.  MySQL comes with a Bulk Loader in the NameSpace which allows you to specify various options and avoid concatenating strings for SQL.  @Crowcoder - thats the bulk load syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem.

```
When you use VB.Net values in MySQL query Remember to start like this '" and end like this "'

'" textbox1.text "'
```

Comment: Now the line is: cmd.CommandText = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" & directory.Text.ToString & "' INTO TABLE '" & database.Text & "'.'" & table.Text & "';"